# find-grep-dired: find exited abnormally with code 1

Tags: dired, grep

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+

I want in Dired to find all files that contain text "**UserOptions**".

1. `M-x find-grep-dired`
2. In folder `ca`
3. `UserOptions`

And here result:

```
  find exited abnormally with code 1 at Sat Dec  2 20:57:13
```

[image: step2]

[image: step2]

Comment: The `find` command that is issued in your Emacsis different from what I see using library [**`find-dired+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el). What I see is this: `find . \( -type f -exec grep -q -e UserOptions \{\} \; \) -exec ls -ld \{\} \;`. (I also don't have a problem with it, but that's likely because of what @p_wiersig's answer says.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use cygwin's or msys `find` command. The error messages shown above seem to come from the windows `find` command that is incompatible with emacs.

See ["Using `grep' and`find' on MS Windows"](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode#toc4) on emacswiki.org

Comment: I use package "xah-find".It's work fine without grep dependency.